# Specification for JSON form object

Tags: yodlee

The API specifies that when requesting a login form for a financial website, it would return a JSON Form object, but never specifies the nature of this object.  API documentation on this topic [here](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getSiteLoginForm).

I need to write a parser so that I can insert the form as html into my page.  Is there anywhere where I can find a parser, or at least see some documentation on this JSON Form object?

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked shows the object that returns.  You need to build the form based on that.  For example when typeName is TEXT, you need to display a  and when it's IF_PASSWORD you create a field of .

Comment: But that's just one example.  It doesn't specify how many different kinds of fields there are or what the unique properties of each field are.

Comment: Yes, welcome to Yodlee's documentation ;).  These are the possible options: TEXT, IF_PASSWORD, OPTIONS, CHECKBOX, RADIO, IF_LOGIN, URL, HIDDEN, IMAGE_URL, CONTENT_URL, CUSTOM and CLUDGE.